# Font is rendering out space inside content box

Tags: html, css

I have a font that's got "padding" on the bottom of the text. I would like to get rid of it completely, but from the research I've done so far, it seems like it might be just the way the font is made?

Is it possible to remove this space at the bottom?

I've tried using `line-height`, also tried turning the parent into `flex` and `align-items: flex-end` to no avail.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bffn.png)

HTML structure looks like this:

```
<span>some text</span>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use negative margin? like `margin-bottom: -5px`, for example

Comment: Images aren't really helpful. Please include code that reproduces your issue, including *all* of the applied CSS.

Comment: From the image, it looks like that's just the space for the descenders.